# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when iterating through pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, typeerror

I have a simple use case. I want to read a text file into a pandas file and iterate through the unique ***id*** s to plot a ***x-y graph***.
Worked for me fine at many other projects but now i get the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. 
At first I got `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`that is why I changed the type of *id* to *int* (see code). But that does not work either. I do not see why. Any ideas?

```
f = open(file,"r+")
with open(file,"r+") as f1:
    data10 = f1.read()
    TESTDATA = StringIO(data11)
df = pd.read_table(TESTDATA, sep=" ")
df.columns = ["x", "y", "id"]

#Astype because i got the error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
df.id = df.id.astype(int)

#get unique values of column id
list1=df['id'].tolist()
list1=list(set(list1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i ,g in list1:
    x = df[df.id==i]['x']
    y = df[df.id==i]['y']
    g.plot(x='x',y='x', marker='o', ax=ax, title="Evaluation")
```

Comment: Can you tell me what data10 and data11 are?

Comment: what are you expecting g will contain in for i,g in list1: .. ?

Comment: Sorry, but this code never ever worked fine anywhere. I have to be as clear as that, because I really thought about how to answer your question and realized, that I didn't even know where to start... You can get help here, but two things from your side please: be honest and show some effort by yourself.

Comment: That said, your error message is thrown because you try to use two variables in a for-loop over a simple list. But a simple list provides only one whatever per iteration, so this is wrong. Throw away the `, g` in the for loop.

Comment: However, the next error will come soon... Use `ax.plot()` instead of `g.plot()`. And why do you plot only your x data, but thst over `x` _and_ `y`?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your code reduces to

```
df = pd.read_table(file, sep=" ")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grpd = df.groupby('id')
for i, g in grpd:
    g.plot(x='x',y='y', marker='o', ax=ax, title="Evaluation")
```

***Explanation:***
I'll step through the code step by step:

```
f = open(file,"r+")
```

**can be deleted** you don't need to open a file before you open it in a `with`-block
But *if* you open it this  way, do not forget to *close* it after you don't need it anymore.

```
with open(file,"r+") as f1:
    data10 = f1.read()
    TESTDATA = StringIO(data11)
```

**can be deleted**
1. weird usage of data10, data11 (it will not work) and StringIO (way too complicated)
2. see next code line

```
df = pd.read_table(file, sep=" ")
```

**OK** if you replace `TESTDATA` simply by `file`, pandas is very powerful at importing files of different flavours...

```
df.columns = ["x", "y", "id"]
```

**OK** if your file doesn't have already it's own header which would fit your needs, which I'd recommend to check perhaps ...

```
#Astype because i got the error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
df.id = df.id.astype(int)
```

**can be deleted**  because your error has nothing to do with that, as I stated in my comment yesterday

```
#get unique values of column id
list1=df['id'].tolist()
list1=list(set(list1))
```

**can be deleted**  if you want unique values of a column in pandas, use `df['id'].unique()`, but you don't need to do everything manually here, as for the target you want to achieve there is `groupby`:

```
grpd = df.groupby('id')
```

This returns a groupby-object, which indeed provides you with groupname *and* group data when you iterate over it, so your loop with two variables would work here:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, g in grpd:
    g.plot(x='x',y='x', marker='o', ax=ax, title="Evaluation")
```

and to be complete: your extra

```
x = df[df.id==i]['x']
y = df[df.id==i]['y']
```

**can be deleted**, too, because this is also included in the idea behind grouping. (And btw, you didn't even use it in your code...)

**In the end** I'd recommend you to read the very basics of Python and pandas, especially file io https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files and pandas grouping https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html